# Активация тэга HTML

Tags: html, bootstrap, flask, jinja2

Возникла небольшая проблема. На странице HTML, я вывожу предупреждение(alert). Делаю следующим образом в коде программы

```
flash('<strong>'+form.username.data+'</strong> успешно зарегистрирован!')
```

На html странице это

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><span>{{ message }}</span></div>
                {% endfor %}        
            {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Хочу чтобы было: **Иванов** успешно зарегистрирован!
Сейчас же выходит `<strong>Иванов</strong> успешно зарегистрирован!`

Есть возможность активизировать тэг `<strong>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы теги не экранировались, нужно отключить автоэкранирование.

Для достижения этого есть три способа:

1)В коде Python обернуть строку HTML в объект Markup перед передачей в шаблон. Это рекомендуемый способ.

2)Внутри шаблона, воспользовавшись фильтром |safe для явной отметки строки, как безопасного HTML ({{ myvariable|safe }})

3)Временно отключить систему автоэкранирования.

Для отключения системы автоэкранирования в шаблонах можно воспользоваться блоком {% autoescape %}:

Пример

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      {% autoescape false %}
      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><span>{{ message }}</span></div>
      {% endautoescape %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался рекомендуемым способом.